# Rewrite rule not redirecting properly

Tags: mod-rewrite

Trying to redirect all contents of a directory to a different URL.
I have:

```
RewriteRule ^Diet\ Plans(.*)$ http://dietplans.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

When invoked via: `abc.com/Diet Plans`
all works as expected - taken to the document root of the redirected domain

But if I invoke it as: `abc.com/Diet Plans/xxx.pdf`
it still goes to the document root rather than `http://dietplans.example.com/xxx.pdf`

What am I doing wrong?

What I want is any reference to the "Diet Plans" directory to redirect to the same location in the new server but without the "Diet Plans" parent directory component.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I took the liberty of editing your post with some formatting - I recommend you read the [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) or take a peek at [the formatting reference provided when you are writing your question](http://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0120a86e29f4970b-pi).

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the L flag.

This means to stop processing the rule set. In this case, since you are searching for any amount of subsequent characters, the root domain will always be found *first*. Thus, all processing will stop.

Comment: But there are no other rules after this one.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using mod_alias instead:

```
Redirect 301 "/Diet Plans" http://dietplans.example.com
```

This will also account for things like `abc.com/Diet Plans/xxx.pdf` -> `http://dietplans.example.com/xxx.pdf`